# how to store char + int as same type and same member in a struct?

Tags: c, types, struct, void

I want to have a single type in a struct that takes one char and one int as i.e. Z84. I have tried to figure this out but I don't have any clue. Would void work? Or does it conflict with different types as the same type?

```
struct exmaple{

whatType? charValueintValue

};
```

I search for a type like int in witch I can store Z84.
**I do not mean this:**

```
struct exmaple{

int number
char value 
};
```

But this would work fine if I can do printf("something:%example", example) or what should I do to use printf on charValueintValue to print that value out with printf?

Comment: I hesitate with caution and wonderment what problem you're **really** trying to solve.

Comment: The way to store a `char` and an `int` in a structure is to have a `char` member and an `int` member. You've told us you don't want that. You haven't told us why. Without that information, it's impossible to tell what the best solution to your actual problem might be.

Answer (score 2):

You should store it as a char* and convert the integer values to ASCII.

```
struct example{
    char value[LENGHT];
};
```

If you want to use the integer, you can also try store them separately:

```
struct example{
    char charValue;
    int intValue;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is easy:

```
struct example {
    char_and_int x;
};
```

Now you have "a single type in a struct".

All you need is to define earlier:

```
struct char_and_int {
    char c;
    int  i;
};
```

Usage:

```
struct example foo = { { 'Z', 89 } };
```

Comment: but how do I use printf when I want to print out the value x? What %something should I use?

Comment: Print the members of the struct one after another:  `printf("%c%i", foo.c, foo.i);`